# How would I go about creating a 2-Dimensional Array of Input

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

My goal is to create a 2-Dimensional array if text based (numerical) inputs. I want to use the same input type box that is used in HTML, like:

```
    <input type="text">
```

The amount of rows and cols would be based off another input in the HTML document. Here's what I have so far:

```
    var rows = document.getElementById("rows");
    var cols = document.getElementById("cols");

    for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
       for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++){ 
       //I don't know what to do here
       }
    }
```

What do I put in the nested for loops to get a multidimensional array of inputs listed? [Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UY2jj.png) of what I am trying to get the thing to look like. The user will be able to click each element and be able to enter a number.

Comment: There should only be one of each `rows` and `cols` elements. Can you include `html` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 It's a lot of code for the HTML. Is there a specific few lines that you are looking for? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by there should only be one of each rows and cols.

Comment: `id` of element in `document` should be unique. There should be at most one each `#row` and `#col` element in `document`. Do you mean `row.value` and `col.value`?

Comment: Oh, in my code I have another input bar that the user controls that is    `<input type="number" id="rows"/>` if that's what you are asking, and `<input type="number" id="cols"/>` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function createTable() {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var rows = +document.getElementById('rows').value;
  var cols = +document.getElementById('cols').value;

  for(var r=0; r<rows; r++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    table.appendChild(tr);
    for(var c=0; c<cols; c++) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      var inp = document.createElement('input');
      inp.setAttribute('type','text');
      td.appendChild(inp);
    }
  }

  var container = document.getElementById('input_container');
  container.innerHTML = '';
  container.appendChild(table);
}
```

```css
td>input {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
Rows : <input type="text" id="rows" value="3">
Cols : <input type="text" id="cols" value="8">
<button onclick="createTable();">Create</button>
<div id="input_container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = document.getElementById("rows");
var cols = document.getElementById("cols");

var multi = [];                                      // the multidimensional array of inputs

for(var i = 0; i < rows; i++){
    var sub = [];                                    // create a new sub-array for each row
    for(var j = 0; j < cols; j++){                   // fill the sub array
        var input = document.createElement("INPUT"); // create an new input
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        sub.push(input);                             // push it into the sub array
    }
    multi.push(sub);                                 // push the sub array into the multi array
}
```

Then `multi` will be somthing like this:

```
[
  [input, input, input, ..., input],
  [input, input, input, ..., input],
  ...
  [input, input, input, ..., input]
]
```

Comment: There should not be more than one `rows` or `cols` element in `document`.

Comment: @guest271314 I don't understand! How is it a multidimensional array if it only has one row or one col?

Comment: Not sure, save for OP is actually trying to set `rows` and `cols` to `.value` of those elements, see Answer by @BulentVural. `id` of element should be unique in `document`. `document.getElementById()` should return at most one element.